# Best way to try to recover FAT32 corrupted usb flash drive

Tags: fat32, file-recovery, filesystem-corruption

I've got a FAT32 USB flash drive (Not mine; I would never store critical data on a FAT32 flash device!) with evident signs of data corruption:

When viewed in Windows 7:

- All or almost all files are inaccessible
- Names replaced by strange ASCII symbols
- Several errors in description

When viewed in Ubuntu:

- Only 1 unknown file is present

My knowledge of data recovery can be traced back to the Norton Ghost 6 era, so I don't know about more modern techniques, what should I do?

Before using a recovery program, is there a way to back it up, to try several methods without further damage?

Comment: `dd` the drive on a linux system to create a bit-wise clone before running any recovery

Comment: Pretty much any file recovery tool can be used what tools have you used after running 'dd' on it?

Comment: Sadly I don't have the drive right now with me, it's from somebody else but I could get it during office hours.

What syntax should I use with dd to make a complete backup?

Comment: I've used the trial version of Capt Nemo Pro to do this with a memory card and a corrupted stick.  There are other fully-functional trial downloads that will do it as well, like Flash File Recovery.  These programs will mount the stick based on what type of partition is detected, and can often recover even deleted files.